# Stm32 AI: What is the in memory structure of the input image data?

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to test X-CUBE-AI on my Stm32F429ZI nucleo board. I'm using Stm32CubeMX, Stm32CubeIDE.

Setup: stmnist_v1.h5, I've PNG files for this dataset.

At first I'd like to test the AI routines with in-memory buffer so I'd like to know what is the input buffer format. So when I have a BMP or an PNG file how to extract to the memory.